# What did the writers mean by this detail in one scene of one episode of "Alfred Hitchcock Presents" from 1957?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, realism, cinema-history

In the 26th episode of season two of "Alfred Hitchcock Presents" titled, "I Killed The Count Part II", first aired in 1957, there is a short scene, or rather a brief moment of one scene, which confuses and intrigues me.

Set in the present (1957), in London (England), it's about a count who has been murdered in his flat ("apartment"). One of the many people interviewed by the very British Scotland Yard expert investigator is a young, beautiful female. It's made clear that she is supposed to be very attractive in the context of the episode's "world".

At one point in the brief interview, she mentions that a guy followed her to her door. She's asked if he went in with her. She looks awkward and says something about, *"At that time in the night?!"*, but soon admits that he did come in briefly. The investigator then asks with a humorous and sort of kindly smirk: "Perhaps... five minutes?" She looks a bit embarrassed and replies: "... Perhaps."

Now, given that this was broadcast on television in the 1950s in the USA, it seems unlikely that they blatantly made an implied sexual reference here, but I've been trying to come up in my head with any plausible explanation other than that.

Do they really mean that he snuck in to her room for five minutes of clothed kissing and hugging? I mean, sure, what do I know? I've never been popular with females, so maybe that's exactly what people do/did when they get the chance, but it *seems* like more was implied. At risk of sounding obscene, my first thought was frankly "blowjob or quick sex", especially given the character's curvy appearance.

If this is out of the question, which I fully accept, then what else might they do for "five minutes" in the middle of the night in her apartment? With her basically blushing talking about it? Maybe it is as innocent as a short "kissing session", but I have my doubts.

There was an overall humorous tone to this scene (really the whole episode, which is one of a three-parter), making me even more confused as to the intentions of the writers and how it would've been perceived back then versus now.

Comment: British person here (although I wasn't around in the 50s). The way I read your quesiton, I think a quickie is exactly what was implied. But I also agree that it seems a bit risque for the period. No evidence either way, hence a comment.

Answer (score -3):

I will answer with a joke.
A duke came back from a long trip. On a way to home he ask his steward what happened when he was gone.  - Nothing - says steward. 
 - Really nothing?
 - well, the dog died. 
 - The dog? Why? 
 - He eaten spoiled meat - Why and where did he found spoiled meat? - From dead horses. - What dead horses? - The one that died after the stable has burned down. - What? What did the stable burned down? - It taken fire from the mansion. - The Mansion? Why the mansion was on fire? - Oh well, the dutchess died and we set night watch and the drapes were set on fire with candles.

Here is ver similar train of thought. "Nothing happened. Well, the guy followed me home. Well he come into my house." A guy who stalk a girl is usually not let into someones apartment.
So the audience are given two clues. One is that the girl is lying, slowly revealing andcontradicting her previous statements. Second is that the guy probably didn't followed her buy accompanied. She knew him and they spend the night together having sex.
That's naughty. For 50's movie.

There is also a play on this kind of questionig in english show "The Fast Show" (I think it was "Brilliant" in US). "Me, the 13th Duke of Wybourne? Here? In the French maids dormitory? At 3 o'clock in the morning? With my reputation? Bingo".